# Extjs 5 grid filter + RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, extjs, filter, grid

I have a simple grid with filter. If I use regexp on the filter then filter is not working. If I don't use regexp on the filter then filter is working.:-) Where is the bug my code?

This is my regexp + filter code:

My simple textfield:

```
{
  xtype: 'textfield',
  id: 'users_gridfilter',
  name: 'users_gridfilter',
  size: 20
}
```

And I have a button listeners:

```
listeners: {
  click: function(){
   var store = Ext.getCmp('users').getStore(), 
   val = new RegExp(Ext.getCmp('users_gridfilter').getValue(), "i");
     store.filterBy(function(rec){
        return rec.get('first_name') === val ||
               rec.get('last_name') === val; }); },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `val` variable is a `RegExp` object, not a string. You are trying to compare field values with `RegExp` objects :)

Try:

```
store.filterBy(function(rec) {
    return val.test(rec.get('first_name')) || val.test(rec.get('last_name'));
})
```